# How to adjust layout before page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I have a jquery code that adjusts text and images sizes according to the width of a main div that stretches out 100% of the browser window. For some reason when I put code into a (document).ready function, it wont ignite. It works perfectly in (window).resize, but whenever the page first loads, it looks atrocious. As soon as you make the web browser smaller or bigger, everything snaps into place. How can I make everything snap into place WHEN the page load?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mainwidth = $('.main').width();
    var mainheight = $('.main').height(mainwidth * .8895);
    var headerwidth = $('.header-middle').width();
    var headerheight = $('.header-middle').height();

    $('.call-us-today').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01836});
    $('.header-paragraph').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01734});
    $('.header-paragraph-footer').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01632});
    $('.top-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .02448});
    $('.graybar-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .03265});
    $('.body-header').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .02245});
    $('.body-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01632});
    $('.footer').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01224});
    $('.banner-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .02244});

    $('.graybar-text').css({'letter-spacing': headerwidth * .00408});
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    resizeDiv();
});

window.onresize = function(event) {
    resizeDiv();
}

function resizeDiv() {
    var mainwidth = $('.main').width();
    var mainheight = $('.main').height(mainwidth * .8895);
    var headerwidth = $('.header-middle').width();
    $('.main').height(mainwidth * .8895)
    $('.logo').width(headerwidth * .049);
    $('.logo').height(headerheight * .7533);
    $('.divider').width(headerwidth * .00204);
    $('.design-image').width(headerwidth * .2547);

    $('.call-us-today').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01836});
    $('.header-paragraph').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01734});
    $('.header-paragraph-footer').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01632});
    $('.top-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .02448});
    $('.graybar-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .03265});
    $('.body-header').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .02245});
    $('.body-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01632});
    $('.footer').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .01224});
    $('.banner-text').css({'font-size': headerwidth * .02244});

    $('.graybar-text').css({'letter-spacing': headerwidth * .00408});
}
```

Comment: Where is you resize function? And a bit of HTML would work too.

Comment: instead of basing your widths off of the main div, why not use viewPort?

Comment: Just chain on `.trigger('resize')` on the resize handler ?

Comment: Would I add a trigger in the document ready function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(document).ready()` fires before all your resources (like images) have finished downloading. Try this instead:

```
$(window).load(function() {
// image manipulation code

});
```

Comment: I've tried this a few times and it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Can you step through your window.resize handler and then step through the window.load handler and see if there are any differences?

Comment: As an aside, have you given any thought to CSS media queries? They are an excellent solution to serving different styles based on the browser's resolution.

Comment: Still no luck. Don't you have to create multiple sized css files if you use viewport? I already have 5 for different browsers. I would hate to have to make 3 or 4 more style sheets for each browser

Comment: Did you step through your two event handlers and see how they differ? Re: media queries, you don't need to create addition CSS files, you simply declare blocks of styles that you wish applied at different resolutions. I'd suggest it is more elegant than fiddling with javascript for that purpose. Here is a good tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Yep, I did. I have a code that has worked for me i the past, not sure why it wont work on this page... I'll edit my post with the code

Comment: So window.resize works but this won't: `$(window).load(function() { resizeDiv(); })` ?

Comment: Found out what it is... Its something to do with this line of code:

$('.logo').height(headerheight * .7533);

and the syntax seems correct :s